# Get all combinations of a list grouped by name

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, generic-list

I have the following list of TestParam... This is just a parameter list that is doing to determine how a query is going to be run. In the following case, the expected result would be to be executed against all the combinations of different parameters. Hence, a list of lists, with CustomerId 33 together with each product Id available in the list...

```
List<TestParam> testList = new List<TestParam>();
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "CustomerId", Value = "33" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "1" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "2" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "3" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "4" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "5" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "6" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "7" });
        testList.Add(new TestParam() { Name = "ProductId", Value = "8" });
```

TestParam is a normal encapsulated parameter class having a name and a value...

```
public class TestParam
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

The end result would be a list of lists, having CustomerId 33, with all the rest of the products. The same result would be acquired if I had different names and values in the list of TestParam (the above is just an example).

The following code, ends up with several lists depending on the combinations of the list above...

```
   // First get a list of distinct unique param collections...
    List<string> distinctParameterNames = new List<string>();
    testList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).ForEach(paramName => {
        distinctParameterNames.Add(paramName.Key);
    });

    // Get counts
    List<int> combinationList = new List<int>();
    foreach (var x in distinctParameterNames) { 
        combinationList.Add(testList.Where(y=>y.Name == x).Count());
    }

    // Will contain 2 lists, one having all combinations of parameters named CustomerId, and another with ProductId combinations...
    List<List<TestParam>> parameterList = new List<List<TestParam>>();
    foreach (var x in distinctParameterNames) {

        // Loop 
        List<TestParam> parameter = new List<TestParam>();
        testList.Where(paramName => paramName.Name == x).ForEach(y =>
        {

            parameter.Add(new TestParam() { Name = y.Name, Value = y.Value });

        });

        parameterList.Add(parameter);

    }
```

It would be an intersect between the list, and the end result will be a list of lists, and each list will have the combinations below... So a run would return (in this case) :

1. Customer 33, Product Id 1
2. Customer 33, Product Id 2
3. Customer 33, Product Id 3
4. Customer 33, Product Id 4
5. Customer 33, Product Id 5
6. Customer 33, Product Id 6
7. Customer 33, Product Id 7
8. Customer 33, Product Id 8

What would be the most efficient and generic way to do this?

Comment: What does the resulting datastructure look like? You say List of list? Why doesnt  Product Id 1 and so have all the products? (if you want all combinations) Is there something special with the first value?

Comment: @Magnus the result will be a List<List<TestParam>>.

Comment: It is a cross set between all the different names in the list. If I have ProductId, ManagerId and CustomerId, I get all the combinations depending on the values I have from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the solution that I was looking for...

```
public static List<List<T>> AllCombinationsOf<T>(params List<T>[] sets)
        {
            // need array bounds checking etc for production
            var combinations = new List<List<T>>();

            // prime the data
            foreach (var value in sets[0])
                combinations.Add(new List<T> { value });

            foreach (var set in sets.Skip(1))
                combinations = AddExtraSet(combinations, set);

            return combinations;
        }

        private static List<List<T>> AddExtraSet<T>
     (List<List<T>> combinations, List<T> set)
        {
            var newCombinations = from value in set
                                  from combination in combinations
                                  select new List<T>(combination) { value };

            return newCombinations.ToList();
        }
```

Usage (continues with my code snippet of the question itself) :

```
var intersection = AllCombinationsOf(parameterList.ToArray());
```

Comment: I think my solution is better because a) it does the same b) it is 3 times shorter

Answer (score 0):

get all the list of customer first like this

```
var customers = from a in testlist where a.name='customerid'
                select a;

var products = from a in testlist where a.name='productid'
                select a;
```

then loop customers

```
for(var c in customers)
{
    loop products
     for(var p in products)
     {
        var customerproducts = new CustomerProducts{
            Customer = c.Name +' ' + c.Value
            Product = p.Name + ' ' + p.value
         };

       then add it into a list 
     }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not generic, and doesn't work if I have several different parameters having different names in the same list. The above snippet which I posted is just an example. If I add in the above list, another entry with name Manager, and value of 1, I would need to add this combination to each and every run.

Answer (score 0):

The list needs to be grouped by `Name`, then it can be joined several times depending on count of groups:

```
        var groups = testList.GroupBy(_ => _.Name);

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TestParam>> result = null;

        foreach (var g in groups)
        {
            var current = g.Select(_ => new[] { _ });
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = current;
                continue;
            }

            result = result.Join(current, _ => true, _ => true, (actual, c) => actual.Concat(c));
        }

        // check result
        foreach (var i in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", i.Select(_ => string.Format("{0}-{1}", _.Name, _.Value))));
        }
```